# unable to assign variable or dynamic data to fusion charts in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fusioncharts

i want to load the dynamic data and show cylinder chart. with static values chart working but variable data unble to assign to value field of fusion chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/qe5ruLqz/8/

```
<td >
            <fusioncharts id="chartContainer1" width="371" height="400" type="cylinder" datasource={{Bin1Data}}></fusioncharts>
        </td>
  <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ng-fusioncharts"]);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('https://example.com', {
                headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic abcd==' }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.names = response.data;
                $scope.decodedFrame = atob($scope.names.dataFrame);
                $scope.decodedFrameNew = $scope.decodedFrame.substring(4);
                $scope.distanceinFeet = $scope.decodedFrameNew * 12.5 * 2.54;
                $scope.Value = $scope.distanceinFeet / 148;
                $scope.bin1Value = $scope.Value.toFixed(2);
                $scope.names.timestamp = new Date($scope.names.timestamp).toLocaleString(); // Parse the date to a localized string
                 $scope.Bin1Data.chart.value[0].value = $scope.bin1Value;// assigning value to chart
            });

            $scope.Bin1Data = {
                "chart": {
                    "caption": "Tank 2",
                    "lowerLimit": "0",
                    "upperLimit": "100",
                    "showValue": "1",
                    "valueBelowPivot": "1",
                    "theme": "fint",
                    "width": '50%',
                    "height": '50%',
                    "value":  [{
                        "value": 0 //unble to assign values here
                    }]

               }

            };
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide different code in question and fiddle. **My answer is based on fiddle!**

Your assignment is incorrect. You should pass data to  `$scope.Bin1Data.chart.value`.

I edited Your fiddle to pass dynamic data. Look for refresh function and button. I think it is good point to go:

http://jsfiddle.net/yt1q2v5f/